# C# Linq-to-SQL timeout on very fast local DB query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm using the following code as the very first DB call in my program, querying a local SQL DB table that includes daily stock price information:

```
public DateTime Read_DailyData_FirstDate(String Symbol)
    {
        using (EquitiesDataContext db = new EquitiesDataContext()) {
            var q =
            (from c in db.DailyDatas
             where (c.Symbol == Symbol)
             orderby c.Date ascending
             select c.Date).FirstOrDefault();
            return q;
        }
    }
```

It gives me a `"Timeout expired"` error on a handful of symbols (approx. 2% of symbols). Manually running the equivalent Top 1 query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio is nearly instantaneous

```
(SELECT top 1 [Date] FROM [Equities].[dbo].[DailyData] where Symbol = 'X' order by Date).
```

I've verified that there are no apparent errors in the DB data itself (all columns prohibit nulls by design, no duplicate dates within each symbol, etc.), and the symbols in question are far from the ones with the longest history.

I initially used .First() instead of .FirstOrDefault(), but switched when I saw the latter being suggested for a related topic. The same error occurs for .First()

Comment: Are there indexes on the database?

Comment: Can you query another table?Have you seen the StackTrace?

Comment: There are indexes on Date and Symbol, as well as a KeyID.

Comment: @GeorgeVovos I can query another table. The issue is that the above LINQ query (for the specific table) works perfectly for the vast majority of symbols, but consistently fails for a small subset of symbols.

Comment: Did you check the query that is generating by LINQ? Maybe for some reason it is not the same as you tested in SQL directly? you can set db.Log = Console.Out; and view generated SQL in console.

Comment: Smells like parameter sniffing - where SQL Server caches a plan for one set of parameters, and it turns out to be bad for a second set of parameters. In T-SQL world, you would use `Option Recompile` or `Option Optimize for Unknown` to work around it. In this case, creating a single index on `Symbol, Date` should make the plan fast in all cases.

Comment: @ntl - Thanks for the db.Log tip. I used it, and this was the query: SELECT top (1) [t0].[Date] 
FROM [dbo].[DailyData] AS [t0] 
where [t0].Symbol = @ p0
order by [t0].[Date] ////// After adding [Equities]. before [dbo], I ran it, and it takes a full second, instead of an instant, to run. Any recs for how to modify the LINQ code to streamline the query? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jack Huang If it takes a full second to execute the query, you should optimize DB and not LINQ. Query is ok and there is no place to make it faster, so you should investigate what is the problem on DB side. You answered about indexes, but from your comment it is not clear if you have index for single Symbol column or index for two columns: Symbol and Date?